# Using KeyboardAvoidingView with a padding on main container

Tags: react-native

I am currently working with React Native Expo and having trouble fixing the notch padding in my main container. I am using the following css to determine a `paddingTop`:

```
flex: 1,
paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
```

Within that container, I have an input wrapped with `KeyboardAvoidingView`. It has the following styling:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
   style={{ flex: 1 }}
   behavior="padding"
>
   ....
   <Input />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

When the `paddingTop` is applied to the main container, it pushed the input below (behind) the keyboard. Is there a way to subtract the paddingTop when `KeyboardAvoidingView` is applied? I have tried to subtract the paddingTop from the height of the main container but that did not work.

EDIT: Here is an outline of the code:

```
<Container style={SafeViewAndroid.AndroidSafeArea}>
   <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      behavior="padding"
   >
      ....
      <Input />
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Container>
```

The `<Container>` comes from NativeBase. My `paddingTop` is in the Container styling.

Comment: You mean there's a KeyboardAvoidingView in View?

Comment: @hongdevelop I updated to what the code looks like. I have the `KeyboardAvoidingView` wrapping the input

Comment: Where is your `paddingTop`??

Comment: @hongdevelop It is in a Container that wraps the KeyboardAvoidingView. I edited the post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `status` values to remove the `height`.

```js
// paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? this.state.height : 0
this.state={
  height : StatusBar.currentHeight
}
...

inputfocus = () => {
  this.setState({
     height : 0
  });
}

onEndEditing = () => {
  this.setState({
     height : StatusBar.currentHeight
  });
}
...
<Input 
onFocus={this.inputfocus}
onEndEditing={this.onEndEditing} // To return to the original height
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When you make paddingTop = 0 on the edit, I think it would then push the top of my container back into the notch portion of the phone. Thoughts?

Comment: If the paddingTop is zero, the end of the container will be aligned with the status bar.